# <img> height inside flexbox with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.dblCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-grow: 2;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.sglCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-basis: 33.33333333%;
    max-width: 33.33333333%;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* height can be fix */
}


/* surrounding styles */
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 40px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="app">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="dblCol">
        <h3>Teaser #1</h3>
        <img src="https://assets9.domestika.org/project-items/001/654/589/lorem_vector-big.png?1467128294" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sglCol">
        <h3>Teaser #2</h3>
        <img src="https://cdn-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-www.enfocus.com/files/media/blog/2017-08-09-Lorem-Ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using flexbox width relative widths. In this case, the right column is 33% wide and the left column stretches up to the remaining space.

The images within these columns now shall be displayed with the same height. This can be a fixed pixel height. But the width of the image should stretch to 100% **BUT** not crack it's ratio. So what I'm trying achieve is, a way to just show the center part of the image as much as possible like shown below.

**Bad**:
[image]

**Good**:
[image]

Can this even be done be CSS? If yes, a hint would be awesome.

Comment: The codepen link got lost: https://codepen.io/axeff/pen/zLjBoP

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

I should already say that in IE it is not supported.

I added the image `image-1` to the image and then in css I added the attribute `object-fit: none`

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.dblCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-grow: 2;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.sglCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-basis: 33.33333333%;
    max-width: 33.33333333%;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* height can be fix */
}

.image-1 {
  object-fit: none; /* ------ attribute add ------ */
}

/* surrounding styles */
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 40px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="app">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="dblCol">
        <h3>Teaser #1</h3>
        <img src="https://assets9.domestika.org/project-items/001/654/589/lorem_vector-big.png?1467128294" class="image-1" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sglCol">
        <h3>Teaser #2</h3>
        <img src="https://cdn-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-www.enfocus.com/files/media/blog/2017-08-09-Lorem-Ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this object-fit is like by default applied to the image tag ?

Comment: The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height and width of its content box. With object-fit: none; image will ignore the height and width of the parent and retain its original size. if you want to read some more information about this - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: cool thanks man i thought it was possible using background only

Answer (score 0):

make it a background use a div and give it a background of the image

```
     .image-container {
       background: your_image;
       background-size: contain;
       height: 60px; //whatever you see fit
       background-position: center;
     }
```

I think this will work for you as images would be hard to handle

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily using a wrapper container with overflow hidden:

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    /*other style there to give it the needed size*/
 }
.wrapper > img{
    width:100%;
 }
```

And then html :

```
<div class="my-item">
    <div class="wrapper"><img src="my/path.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

It should works because your picture will get the same width than the wrapper AND because it doesn't constraints it's height.

Answer (score 0):

Use     `object-fit: none;` to `img`

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.dblCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-grow: 2;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.sglCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-basis: 33.33333333%;
    max-width: 33.33333333%;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* height can be fix */
 object-fit: none;
}


/* surrounding styles */
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 40px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="app">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="dblCol">
        <h3>Teaser #1</h3>
        <img src="https://assets9.domestika.org/project-items/001/654/589/lorem_vector-big.png?1467128294" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sglCol">
        <h3>Teaser #2</h3>
        <img src="https://cdn-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-www.enfocus.com/files/media/blog/2017-08-09-Lorem-Ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (from my point of view) is to view the image as `background-image`.

First change the `<img>` tag into `<div>` tag, then add the needed css.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.dblCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-grow: 2;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.sglCol {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    flex-basis: 33.33333333%;
    max-width: 33.33333333%;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* height can be fix */
}
div.img {
    background-image: url(https://assets9.domestika.org/project-items/001/654/589/lorem_vector-big.png?1467128294);
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%; /* you can put the position you want */
}

/* surrounding styles */
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.app {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 40px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="app">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="dblCol">
        <h3>Teaser #1</h3>
        <div class="img"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sglCol">
        <h3>Teaser #2</h3>
        <img src="https://cdn-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-www.enfocus.com/files/media/blog/2017-08-09-Lorem-Ipsum/lorem-ipsum.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```